# Using FindRoot on a system of equations with a singular Jacobian

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of $n$ ODEs $\frac{dx_i}{dt} = f_i(x_1.\ldots,x_n)$, which I would like to solve at steady state.

However, $\sum_{i} x_i = 1$, and so it's actually only an $n-1$-dimensional system. As a result, the jacobian for my system is singular everywhere (which FindRoot tells me when I try to use it). Is there anyway I can get Find Root to work with this, without rewriting the equations in terms of the $n-1$ variables?

For example, what I would like to do is the following:

```
eqn1 = y-2x*y;
eqn2 = 2x*y-y;
FindRoot[{eqn1==0,eqn2==0,x+y==1},{{x,0.2},{y,0.2}}].
```

I know I can use NSolve instead in this scenario, but for the system I'm actually working with, NSolve doesn't compute it in a reasonable time.

This system doesn't actually throw the Jacobian error, but it is a similar system, so I imagine if I can do it for this system, my system of interest will work with the same method.

Comment: Please provide code (InputForm) for a concrete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the [Affine Covariant Newton solver](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationMethodsForSolvingNonlinearEquations.html#45025331) and it's options.

Comment: @BobHanlon Apologies. I have added an example detailing the kind of thing I would like to be able to do.

Comment: `{min, arg} = Minimize[{eqn1^2 + eqn2^2, x + y == 1}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Does Minimize work in the same way as FindMinimum? I've tried using FindMinimum, but it looks like there are quite a few very small minima in it. The solution varies quite substantially depending on starting conditions, but both with an (almost) equally low function value ($10^{-7}$)

Comment: It may soundsweird, however, FindInstance[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x + y == 1}, {x, y}, Reals] it your case works.

Comment: "`Minimize` finds the global minimum of f subject to the constraints given" and "`NMinimize` always attempts to find a global minimum of f subject to the constraints given"; whereas, `FindMinimum` "searches for a local minimum". I would only use `FindMinimum` if neither `Minimize` nor `NMinimize` were successful.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but have you tried `Solve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x + y == 1}, {x, y}]`?

Comment: Can you include an example that shows the error you're trying to avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce an additional variable (here a) that you use nowhere in the equations. (It's just to provide three variables for three equations.)

```
eqn1 = y - 2 x*y;
eqn2 = 2 x*y - y;
FindRoot[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, (x + y - 1) == 0}, 
    {{x, 0.2}, {y, 2}, {a, 2}}]

(*   {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5, a -> 2.}   *)

eqn1 = y - 2 x*y;
eqn2 = 2 x*y - y;
FindRoot[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, (x + y - 1) == 0}, 
   {{x, 1.2}, {y, 2}, {a, 1}}]

(*   {x -> 1., y -> -7.38374*10^-28, a -> 1.}   *)
```